# Focus to an image of a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, image, focus

I have 4 images that when I click them they show information under the images and when I click the last ones the images go under the page and whens the new page loads with that information I have to go down with scroller to see the image and information of the last image.

I want to put focus to the last image when the new page loading.

I do this but it's not working:

```
<script>
function setFocusToTextBox(){
    document.getElementById("abc").focus();
}
</script>

<img src="images/Practidose.fw.png" alt="" width="770" height="150" id="abc" onclick="setFocusToTextBox()"/>
```

Picture of the 4 images and when I click the last one I want to focus that image when the new page loads:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not fully sure of why you want to focus the image you are ON, but try

```
function setFocusToTextBox(){
    document.getElementById("abc").scrollIntoView();
}
```

If onload:

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("abc").scrollIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`.focus()` can normally only be applied to links or form inputs.

However, you can use it on arbitrary elements by giving the element a `tabindex` attribute.

This is usually a good idea for accessibility reasons anyway if you want to make use of `onClick` handlers, as this will help keyboard navigation and other accessibility tools understand that your element is supposed to be clickable.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can give an element `tabindex="0"` to make it focusable, and this doesn't require you to specify an actual value for every other element!