# How to set focus on an image on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to set the focus on an  on page load?  I have found documentation stating to use the `autofocus` attribute but the documentation says that attribute only applies to `input`, `button`, `textarea`, and `select`.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23132450/13405106)?

Comment: What is the reason why you need to set the focus for the image?

Comment: Its a site that was handed to me.  The design has an image in the top left corner and <a href> tags as navigation on the top right.  A click on the image has an action.  The owner of the site wants the focus set on the image on page load so if the user hits the enter key, the same action gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `scrollIntoView` method on window onload

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("ID_OF_IMAGE").scrollIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for something like that:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.querySelector(".classFromImage").focus();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is search for the `img` element with the `autofocus` attribute and set the focus after the DOM is read. You also need to set the `tabindex` to get that working.

I would only search for `img[autofocus]` so that you don't mess too much around with the default behavior.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let elm = document.querySelector("img[autofocus]")
  if (elm) {
    elm.focus()
  }
})
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

:focus {
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img autofocus tabindex="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can focus a nonfocusable element by adding tabindex="0" attribute to the tag and use focus() method with js.

```
<img class="focusable" tabindex="0" src="#"/>
```

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.querySelector(".focusable").focus();
})
```